# how to change status from pending to processing

Tags: magento-1.9, php, orders, order-state

I want to change order status from pending to processing in Magento 
1.9, how can I do this?

Comment: Is this with code or within admin?

Answer (score 3):

The states like "pending" and "processing" change based on certain conditions. You can define custom statuses but those are always assigned to one of those states.

To get from "pending" from "processing", create an invoice or a shipment. Orders become "processing" if one of these exist but not both.

**Update:** I see, you tagged the post with [php](/questions/tagged/php). Programmatically, you can change the state like this:

```
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
```

Note that there are some guards in place before the order is saved. You cannot change from any to any state, but from pending to processing it's always possible.

Comment: can you please share the file location where i can update this code

Comment: No because I have no idea where you want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what consequences it may have but I managed to change the "State" and "Status" of the order directly in the database using following query:

```
UPDATE `sales_flat_order` SET `state` = 'processing', `status` = 'processing' WHERE `sales_flat_order`.`increment_id` = [your order];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it programatically, you can use this code

```
$orderId = YOUR_ORDER_ID;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

$orderIncrementId = YOUR_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);

/**
 * change order status to 'Completed'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to 'Pending'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to 'Pending Paypal'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to 'Processing'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to 'Completed'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to 'Closed'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to 'Canceled'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true)->save();

/**
 * change order status to 'Holded'
 */
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED, true)->save();
```

Otherwise, you can do it from admin panel as well.